Use of clone3 syscall results in SEGFAULT
on Linux arm64 I'm trying to implement syscalls via both clone and clone3, but I'm unable to start the thread (thus cloning a process and then execve works). Here is the code.
unsigned long flags = (CLONE_VM | 
            CLONE_FS | 
            CLONE_FILES | 
            CLONE_SYSVSEM |
            CLONE_SIGHAND | 
            CLONE_SETTLS |
            CLONE_THREAD | 
            CLONE_PARENT_SETTID |
            CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID);

size_t stack_size = 8*1024*1024;

void *stack = mmap(NULL, 
        stack_size, 
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
        MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_GROWSDOWN, 
        -1, 
        0);

struct clone_args args = { 0 };
args.flags = flags;
args.tls = stack;
args.stack = stack + 0x1000;
args.stack_size = stack_size;

int ret = _syscall_clone3(&args, sizeof(struct clone_args));
if (ret < 0)
{
    return -1;
}

if (ret != 0) {
    // This is printed on console
    printf("continue from thread %d\n", gettid());
}
else {
    // This never gets executed
    printf("In thread %d\n", gettid());
        start_routine(arg);
    exit(0);
}

For completion, _syscall_clone3() func is defined in a dedicated asm file as
__syscall_clone3:
    mov x8, #435
    svc #0
    ret

Thanks very much in advance.
What to expect is to start a thread and call its start_routine(), like pthread_create() does.
Edit: reading Craig's and Nate's comment, the debugger really shows empty stack, this may be the reason for segfault. Following this tip, I suspect the compiler does not fill the stack correctly, so it's maybe a problem of how C lang works.
Further inspecting how libc implementations work, I noticed some of these implements a wrap function of start_routine in assembly. To keep basic due to my limited knowledge of arm64 asm, I modified func to
// __syscall_clone3(args, sizeof(args), start_routine, start_routine_arg)
__syscall_clone3:
    mov x8, #435
    svc #0
    ...
    mov x0, x3
    blr x2
    ret

And this seems to work correctly at this mo.
So thank you very much (even if indirectly, you guys solve it)!

Just a guess: stack + 0x1000 --> stack - 0x1000? Also check return value from mmap. and args.stack_size = stack_size - 0x1000;?

Thanks for your proposal but it still segfaults '(

Have your debugger show you the exact source line and instruction where the fault occurs, and the values of all relevant variables and registers. Then share them with us, along with disassembly of the surrounding code.
